# How do I setup Jenkins to build all of my versions of a project?

Tags: version-control, continuous-integration, hudson, jenkins

I'm learning the whole version control thing with subversion and using trunk, branch, tags etc for all my different workings/versions of a project. I'm also trying to get up to speed with using continuous integration with Jenkins (tried ccnet, what a nightmare to setup!).

So my question is, if I have the following areas in my project SVN:

```
file:///E:/Data/SVN/MyProject/trunk
file:///E:/Data/SVN/MyProject/tags/version_1.0
file:///E:/Data/SVN/MyProject/branch/version_1.1
```

.. what is best practice regarding setting up this build project in Jenkins so that all of the different areas in my SVN are continuously monitored and any changes built?

Would I setup one project with several source code repositories, one for each version/trunk etc? Or would I setup multiple build projects? How do I do it?

**EDIT:** Should I be using a matrix project for this (Build multi-configuration project)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set up multiple jobs, one for each branch/tag that you want to build. Once you get one job working well, you can copy it to create the rest, changing just the SVN URL.

You should also get rid of old jobs as you stop maintaining those tags/branches so that your Jenkins configuration doesn't get out of control.

Answer (score 6):

For nightly builds (those that run relatively infrequently and take longer time, usually due to more automated testing done in them) a matrix project is a good fit. Its main advantage is 'one point of change' - you do not have to edit multiple jobs in order to introduce the same change into your builds.  That of course works only in cases where the jobs have little variation among branches (that variation, by the way, can often be niftily handled by [Run Condition Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Run+Condition+Plugin)).

Multi-configuration project is probably not the best fit for delivery builds in this case (delivery builds are run when a developer commits to repository to check that his/her changes integrate well). The reason being that if you commit to trunk you want to build only the trunk, but a matrix build will build everything (consuming computing resources and time).

For delivery builds I would go with a parameterized build, where the main parameter would be the branch to build. That build can be triggered by an SVN hook (see [this document](http://jenkins-ci.org/node/212)). Alternatively, you can associate a trigger build per every branch that would poll the branch (via [Subversion plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Subversion+Plugin)) and trigger your main build with appropriate parameters via [Parameterized Trigger plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin).

By the way, I actually use all the above-mentioned approaches (except for SVN hooks, that I no longer do for not entirely technical reasons).